# Calling custom methods in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra

I am trying to call a custom method on form input in Sinatra, but i cant get it to work.

Here is the code

the_app.rb

```
class TheApp < Sinatra::Base

require 'string.rb'

get "/" do
erb :index
end

post '/' do  
@var = "#{params[:post][:message]}"
@var1 = @var.mymethod
puts "#{@var1}"
end

end
```

index.erb

```
<form action="/" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="post[message]">  
<input type="submit">  
</form>
```

string.rb

```
class String

   def mymethod

   @var.reverse

   end

end
```

I want to perform logic on the input text, i just need to know how run a custom method on the @var.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, when adding a method to the String class, you need to reverse the string object itself (so `@var1.reverse` becomes `self.reverse`)

Also when you do `puts "#{@var1}"` you can do `puts @var1`, but this will print the var in sinatra's logger (which is commonly STDOUT)

The `puts` itself will return `nil`, and sinatra will output nil's string value which is `""`
and you won't see anything in the browser (blank page), here is a working example:

```
require 'sinatra'
class String
    def mymethod
        self.reverse
    end
end
get '/' do
    erb :index
end

post '/' do  
    params[:post][:message].mymethod
end
__END__
@@index
<form action="/" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="post[message]">  
<input type="submit">  
</form>
```

Here are some ruby books:

http://poignant.guide/ - talking foxes - awesome reading :)

http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ - also awesome reading